# Length of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

To my understanding, every basis of a vector space should have the same length, i.e. the dimension of the vector space. The vector space
$$V=\{(x,3x): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
has a basis $\{(1,3)\}$. But $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ is also a basis since it spans the vector space and $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are linearly independent. But that's not possible since all bases should have the same length. I feel like I am missing something obvious?

Comment: Seems like you’re understanding the phrase “spans the vector space” differently from its conventional meaning: If set of vectors spans some space, it usually means that this space is equal to their linear span, not simply a subset of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ cannot be a basis since $(1,0),(0,1)\notin V$. Elements in the basis must be in the vector space.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thank you! This was bugging me for a while.